# How to list with Json with [String:generic struct]

Tags: sections, swiftui-list

I have this struct, :

```
// MARK: - JsonAPIData
struct JsonAPIData: Codable {
    let data: [String: APIData]
    let success: Bool
}

// MARK: - Datum
struct APIData: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let maxVersion, minVersion: Int
}
```

and I want to use these Structures to create a list of data in SwiftUI. I tried this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var results: JsonAPIData

    var body: some View {
        List(results.data.values) { data in
            Text("\(data)")
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.loadData()
        }
    }

    func loadData() {
        //My code to load `results`
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

but I had this error:

```
Initializer 'init(_:rowContent:)' requires that 'Dictionary<String, APIData>.Values' conform to 'RandomAccessCollection'
```

How can I fix it for list `keys` and `values` of `APIData`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this: (but keep in mind: if you loop over dictionaries the order is random....)

```
struct JsonAPIData: Codable {
    let data: [String: APIData]
    let success: Bool
}

// MARK: - Datum
struct APIData: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let maxVersion, minVersion: Int
}

struct ContentView: View {

    func getKeys() -> [String] {
        return results.data.map{$0.key}
    }

    func getValues() -> [APIData] {
        return results.data.map{$0.value}
    }

    @State var results: JsonAPIData


    var body: some View {
        List(getKeys(), id: \.self) { key in
            Text("\(self.results.data[key]!.maxVersion)")
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.loadData()
        }
    }

    func loadData() {
        //My code to load `results`
    }
```